# Powering a RPi 4 a 6V Peristaltic motor (~4mA) and 2 12V Peristaltic motors wired to 8 Relay module from 12V variable power supply

Tags: pi-4, hardware, power-supply, dc-motor

I am creating a smart garden panel basically which is incorporating a RPi 4 as the brains and has 3 peristaltic motors. 2 of which are 12V and 1 is 6V which draws about 4mA of current to run, this is the motor I am having problem powering. There is also an 8 Relay module that the motors are being switched by so not directly to RPi. The pi is wirelessly communicating with a ESP8266 that has sensors for monitoring the plants soil moisture, humidity, temp, & CO2. Currently I have a 12v variable power supply powering everything except for the Pi. Currently I have built 2 circuits that step the 12V down to 5v running the 8 relay module, and 2nd circuit also part of my current problem brings it down to 6v for the 1 motor. The relay circuit is just using a 5v Voltage Reg. to do this with caps and resistors keeping everything smooth and safe. The motor (problem) circuit I am using an LM317 I believe which is a variable voltage regulator, now I am able to get the voltage to the motor in a variable range 6-10v (I forget exact #s at moment) I have found my problem to be the current is not high enough to power the motor which runs from my bench-top PSU at 4mA while the circuit I built is 2mA maybe even .2mA (cannot remember at moment). So can anyone help me figure out a better way to do this setup or build a more efficient circuit to power this motor? I have looked at different ways of using the LM317 and a darlington transistor setup to source more current? I am still learning everything and have probably a medium understanding of electrical work. I am currently a junior a Drexel for Computer Engineering so have some moderate understanding. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am at work while writing this lol but can post pictures and have more accurate information when I get home.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs if you want anyone to read your question.

Comment: Maybe you have gotten your **units** all mixed up?? The [LM317](https://www.ti.com/product/LM317) is a linear voltage regulator that can supply far more current (up to 1.5 Amperes) than the `"4 mA ... 2mA maybe even .2mA ..."`  that you mention in your question. You should get your facts straightened out & re-write your question.